# How to intervene between app icon and Windows Phone system?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Everybody, 
I'm new to Windows Phone programming and I have some questions. 
Firstly, to explain, When I touch some app's icons like "Messaging", "Office", "Phone"... in the app's list, WP system will call to the storage area to run and show the app's content: 
 Messaging - Show your massages 
Office - run the Office app and show files 
...etc... 
And my demand is to write an app that can intervene between them, like this picture: 
Number "1" is the app's icon, I will touch it. 
Number "3" is the app's content that showed after I touch the app's icon 
And now I want to work with the connection between "1" and "3", that's number "2".

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can not. By this i mean, if you want to intervene the launch of an app other than yours, its not possible. No APIs for that and apps are protected.

But if you are talking about you app, that you are building, when the user touches the app icon and launch the app you have some events firing in between. You can use these events to do some work but you cannot access the actual start up process of the app and intervene in that.

You need to study up on [Application Life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) and [Application Activation and Deactivation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx). Also when loading a page in the app you also have some events like [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(VS.95).aspx), [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom(v=vs.95).aspx) etc to handle navigation between pages.

***BUT, What you want here is to intervene in the start up process of another app beside yours you can not do it. That capability is not there.***

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is there anyway to do with the native C++ code ?

Comment: Not that i know of and probably not. Coz the app start up process is secured and WP is tough on security. So even in C++ you will not be getting any access to other app start up process